# Using Jenkins for Gulp based project

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, gulp, jenkins-plugins

I have a project which uses gulp as a local builder. I want to use Jenkins for versioning my project. How can i setup jenkins for gulp based projects?

Comment: Jenkins can execute shell commands. Configure it to run your gulp tasks.

Comment: can please send any step wise step guide

Answer (score 10):

You will find here a guide on how to setup your Jenkins machine to handle javascscript builds, specifically: how to get to the point of installing your npm packages and running a task runner (gulp/grunt). 
http://g00glen00b.be/continuous-integration-javascript/

It details how to install bower and grunt, but changing one of the commands to install gulp instead of grunt-cli should be all that you need to change:

instead of :

```
npm install -g bower grunt-cli
```

you would run:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Also, feel free to skip the parts about SonarQube.

Answer (score 9):

it's strange to see it unanswered.
firstly you should install node and to add its path to PATH variable
after that you are free to use something like
`node node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js yourtaskname` as your build step

Answer (score 2):

Simply specify the path to the your gulp file followed by the task name e.g.

path_to_gulp_file taskname